# Does the hyper-v guest firewall depend on the host configuration?

Tags: windows, firewall, hyper-v

I am really confused about the behavior of hyper-v virtual machines. We are using a Hyper-V host with 6 virtual machines for an app with docker containers. 3 of them are running Windows Server 2012 and the rest are running Windows Server 2016 The problem is, we allow a port through the firewall, then start the container bound to that port but we cannot access the through Internet. We can access through VPN just fine. The container's firewall rules are ok too.

I am guessing it is the host's firewall configuration. Should the host also allow the connections to the guest virtual machine, or could it be another problem? How can I validate that the ports are open and this is a host-machine issue?

We have very limited knowledge of the underlying server infrastructure as we rent from a third party. The machine is dedicated but we do not have access to the hyper-v settings, nor the bare-metal. As working with support tickets is really slow, is there a way to access the hyper-v host settings through the VM, or some steps to take to disable host's interference with the guest machine firewall settings?

Comment: `I am guessing it is the host's firewall configuration` - It isn't.

Comment: Oh? So any idea what could be the problem? Maybe Server-farm's hardware firewall?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Hyper-V guests do not depend on the host firewall configuration. I can suggest you check your domain/group firewall configuration. However, you can try check Virtual Switch firewall [settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn375962(v=ws.11)).